# How to connect to server through ssh with os in virtualbox ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04

I have ubuntu 14.04 installed as a  guest os in virtual box, with host os of windows 8.1

Now I want to connect to another IP (server) in ubuntu through 'ssh' command, but due to virtual box, I am not able to do it.

How to connect to another ubuntu machine in virtual box???

**Note - I require my internet connectivity in ubuntu, while connecting to the server**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that your host (Windows 8.1) is connected to the internet.

Then please change the setting of your virtual machine, on the network section please select NAT or bridged adapter. The easiest one is the NAT because the virtual box will handle the IP assignment (use dhcp mode on your ubuntu OS), but if you use bridged adapter you should define the IP address manually by your self.

If it's done right, your ubuntu will have access to the internet and you can do SSH using the internet.

Comment: Yes it worked, but I am not able to copy files from another computer through scp command. Can you please help me in that???

Comment: Do any of the computer (ubuntu and remote machine) use proxy..??please use -v option to use verbose mode, and perhaps you can see the error in there.

Comment: Yes I tried to do it with -v and I got the following results:

Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host 192.168.36.19, user karanubuntu, command scp -v -t /home/karanubuntu
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.36.19 [192.168.36.19] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.36.19 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.168.36.19 port 22: Connection timed out
lost connection

Comment: Please read this thread, hope it can help you.
http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2092697.html